# Is it possible to show how bash globbing works by doing?

Tags: wildcards

I am teaching someone how bash globbing works. I would like to show (via some bash debugging feature if possible) how bash expands the patterns prior to invoking the command. For instance I would like to do the following:

```
ls -l file*.txt
```

Then I would like bash to show what the `file*.txt` expanded to:

```
ls -l file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
```

I know how to do this using `bash -x` from within a script but I would prefer to do it in the interactive shell so that I don't have to introduce ideas about scripts. Is there a way to do this in *interactive mode*?

Comment: `echo file*.txt`?

Comment: Thanks Joe. That works but I would like to be able to display the intermediate step for any command such as `cp file*.txt dir1/` expanded to `cp file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt dir1`

Comment: ZSH does this by default when you tab complete on a glob.

Comment: @thrig awesome! I tried that with `zsh` and it worked with tab completion. I will use that if I cannot figure out how to print the expanded content in `bash`

Comment: You can `set -x` in the interactive shell too...

Comment: @sshekhar1980 see my answer for doing this in `bash`

Comment: You may be interested in: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

You can simply echo the whole command:

```
echo ls -l file*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it's basically what I usually set in my `.inputrc` to get `zsh` like behavior in `bash`:

```bsh
set show-all-if-unmodified on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

Place the above lines in `~.inputrc` and you're good to go. When doing something like `ls *.txt` just tab and it should glob everything for you and output the matching files.

EDIT: quotes from `man bash`:

> **show-all-if-ambiguous (Off)**
> This  alters the default behavior of the completion functions.  If set to On, words which have more than one possible completion cause the matches to be listed  immediately  instead  of  ringing  the bell.
>
> **show-all-if-unmodified (Off)**
> This alters the default behavior of the completion functions in a fashion  similar to show-all-if-ambiguous. If set to On, words which have more than one  possible  completion  without any  possible  partial  completion (the possible completions don't share a common prefix) cause the matches to be listed immediately instead of ringing the bell.

EDIT2: example output

```bsh
$ ls *
books    dev    music   templates
$ ls *
```

Though it won't work if the one would try to expand the following (as it would try to complete the later argument `~/some/other/folder`:

```bsh
$ cd * ~/some/other/folder
```

Comment: Does it have it be in `~.inputrc`? Or can I put it in `~.profile` on my Ubuntu?

Comment: It should be in `~.inputrc` as it's the `readline` utility startup configuration file. Sincerely I have not tried to put it elsewhere (because docs clearly state where it belongs to). You may try but I doubt it would work out.

Comment: I tried it but it does not seem to work. Is this all I needed to put in there? `sshekhar1980@:~$ cat .inputrc 
set show-all-if-unmodified on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on`

Comment: What command have you tried to expand? It's indeed what is necessary to make it work on my machine. What is your `bash` version? Mine is `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release`. Yet it should work with an older versions as well. Have you restarted the shell after editing `~.inputrc`?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). Yeah after making that change I restarted the shell and rebooted once just to make sure.

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify: the expected behavior would be slightly different from `zsh` so typing `ls B*` and pressing tab it would produce a line below with the expended results (e.g. `Books  Bills  Bars` etc). It won't substitute a `B*` itself.